# Filter list of dictionaries by upper/lower limit on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list of dictionaries that I am trying to write a filter function for. The parameters to filter by will be given as a dictionary where the keys will be strings (matching the keys in the list of dictionaries to be filtered) and the values will be a list with an upper and lower limit.

Example list of dictionaries to be filtered:

```
test_list = [{'hello':1, 'goodbye':4}, {'hello':7, 'goodbye':6}, {'hello': 4, 'goodbye': 2}]
```

Example filtering parameters:

```
params = {'hello':[1, 6], 'goodbye':[5, 8]}
```

The function I've written is as follows:

```
def filter_list(target_list, **kwargs):
    filtered_list = target_list
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        for target in filtered_list:
            if target[k]<v[0] or target[k]>v[1]:
                filtered_list.remove(target)
    return filtered_list
```

For some reason the second parameter is not being checked, and the output I get is:

```
filter_it = filter_list(test_list, **params)
print(filter_it)

>>[{'hello': 4, 'goodbye': 2}]
```

Why is this? By my reckoning none of the items in the list of dictionaries should pass the criteria. But if I change the parameters to:

```
params = {'hello':[1, 8], 'goodbye':[5, 8]}
```

The output is now:

```
>>[{'hello': 7, 'goodbye': 6}]
```

The real data this is going to be used on is a list of about 2500 dictionaries, each having about 45-50 key:value pairs. I need to be able to filter by an arbitrary number of parameters, as I won't always want to specify upper and lower limits on each, hence why I'm not hard-coding a comparison with each parameter.

Thanks in advance for all/any help!

Comment: Your params are the same. But you give different result.

Comment: @XuQiushi yes, apologies - I've just edited it!

Comment: You are removing list items while iterating over them..

Comment: @adirabargil yeah. The idea was to remove items from the list on each iteration if they didn't meet the condition being evaluated. They then should not be there on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: all(lower < x[key] < upper 
                                   for key, (lower, upper) in params.items()),
                     test_list))
```

Comment: This is throwing  a SyntaxError at me. Is something missing? Sorry - I don't know how to use lambda functions yet so I'm not sure how to correct it myself!

Comment: @ggarfield yeah, i've deleted a comma and parentheses accidentally. fixed.

Comment: That works! Thank you! Could you explain what the lambda function actually does please? That way I can implement it in other places in future :)

Comment: @ggarfield take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful

Answer (score 0):

You have a issue in this peice of code:

```
for target in filtered_list:
      if target[k]>=v[0] and  target[k]<=v[1]:
            filtered_list.remove(target)
```

You are removing items from iterable Type which prevent you from certain loops... this is a way to filter a list you better do something like this:

```
filtered_list = [target for target in filtered_list if target[k]<v[0] or target[k]>v[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer, so I just give some additional explanation for you.

First, your code is deleting an item from a list while iterating over the list. So it will ignore some items. For example, when you delete the second item of a list. Then it will get the fourth item next loop.

I have modified your original code, so you can understand what it should be.

First, you can use copy instead move.

```
def filter_list_with_copy(target_list, **kwargs):
    filtered_list = []
    for target in target_list:
        all_satisfied = True
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if target[k] < v[0] or target[k] > v[1]:
                all_satisfied = False
                break
        if all_satisfied:
            filtered_list.append(target)
    return filtered_list
```

Second, you can use `while` instead `for`. Then you can control your loop index.

```
def filter_list_with_while(target_list, **kwargs):
    filtered_list = target_list
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        filtered_index = 0
        filtered_list_length = len(filtered_list)
        while filtered_index < filtered_list_length:
            target = filtered_list[filtered_index]
            if target[k] < v[0] or target[k] > v[1]:
                filtered_list.remove(target)
                filtered_list_length = len(filtered_list)
            else:
                filtered_index += 1
    return filtered_list
```